# Google Sheet Macro Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I select the **entire rows** (not column, not cells) where I find any cell containing "Approved" and set the background colour of the **whole number of rows** to Green and the **text contained by these rows** to White?

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional Formatting, no need of scripting (or macro)

#### Range:

- `1:1000`

#### Custom formula:

- `=COUNTIF(1:1,"Approved") > 0`

#### Formatting style:

- Fill - Green
- Text Color - White

#### Result:

[image: Result]